# How can I create a new image with support of alpha channel with Graphicsmagick in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, transparency, alpha, graphicsmagick

I want to create a grid image with white lines and alpha channel so I can compose this on another image. How can I apply alpha channel to  gridImage instance instead of a solid background and how can I change the color of the drawn lines with drawLine method ?

```
 var gridImage = new gm(imageWidth,imageHeight,"white");
    gridImage.channel("Opacity");
    gridImage.drawLine(10,0,10,200);
    gridImage.strokeWidth(3);
    gridImage.borderColor("white");
    gridImage.fill("white");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak `node` because I am allergic to all those parentheses, and I don't understand exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I can show you something that may help you work out how to do what you want - hopefully.

I am using **ImageMagick** but the concept is similar. The following command creates a solid magenta square of 100x100. It then creates a smaller, 50x50 pattern in black and white and copies that into the opacity channel so that the smaller 50x50 square gets holes punched in it.

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:magenta                \
    \( -size 50x50 pattern:HS_CROSS -negate \) \
       -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Here's another one:

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:cyan         \
   \( -size 100x100 xc:white -fill black -draw "circle 50,50 50,60" -alpha off \) \
      -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you dear Mark. Actually I needed the same thing but done in nod JS. Though node uses a wrapper for Graphicsmagick and Imagemagick the commands are a bit different than those you would use in terminal. But I finally found what I needed. Thank you for your help.